# R code: CEV Model & MC simulation

Tags: r, montecarlo

No idea how to implement this code on R, any help is welcome!

We assume that the underlying process ST follows a CEV model.

- Evaluate the Expected Value of the following payoff using the MC method. Write an efficient code. (Hint: system.time() r function could be useful).

max{ST - K, 0} **1** a_1 ≤ ST_1 ≤ b_1, **1** a_1 ≤ ST_2 ≤ b_1, **1** a_1 ≤ ST_3 ≤ b_1

where a_1 < b_1 and **1** is an indicator function, T1 =0.25*T, T2 =0.5*T, T3 =0.75*T

(Hint: The final time T in your code must be an input fixed by the user. If the user chooses T = 10 than T1 =10*0.25 = 2.5 and so on)

- Compute the upper and lower bound of the MC price
- For each model parameter write a code for evaluating the corresponding sensitivity measure

Online I found some strings of code, but they seem to be too advance for a student like me.